# Ubuntu WiFi problem installation problem shutdown restart problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown, reboot

I'm working on this for about 4 days and I tried everything and can't do anything so please do not suggest the same solutions on the Internet. Here is the problem.  I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 10 installed as the first OS than the Ubuntu. My computer is Asus x550V with Nvidia gtx950m. The installation was successful,  however It come up with a problem that I cannot shutdown or restart. I tried everything including quiet splash methods to graphics upgrade NONE of them work. But i was able to shut down through terminal via

```
sudo shutdown - v - h now
```

But it is not the only problem. The OS sometimes suddenly disconnect from WiFi and never connect (can't see the SSID even) until a restart. So wanted to install 16.04. I downloaded the iso burned to a cd also to a USB stick. But NONE of them was able to start installation. Neither I select try Ubuntu without installing nor install Ubuntu option works,  they stuck on the Ubuntu loading screen(as the same happens shutdown or restart).

I went to the code page by clicking F8,  when I click one of these install options the codes start to show up and it stops at something about Intel.blablabla but in some other tries I saw something with Bluetooth. Than I saw a post, turned the fast boot off through Windows and also through bios. The CSM was turned off also. I didn't see an option about uefi or legacy so I didn't do anything about that. Now I can't even shutdown through terminal,  and my hard disk drive is slowing down because of the shutdowns through the power button. I really need to solve this quick.

also when the terminal was working, after I use the code to shutdown, the computer was able to shutdown correctly through the gui(not the power button, the icon) until I download something through terminal (sudo apt get...)) why I can't install Ubuntu or shut it down even... I was able to get to installation screen (16.04 with USB stick) but I checked the download updates when installing(deadliest mistake) when downloading it disconnected and froze there.  Therfore I had to shutdown and restart which I was never able to Get to the installation again.

Please help me and save my pc from being shutdown by power button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!   A bit of formatting could really help clear up this post.  A bunch of paragraph breaks would definitely help make it less overwhelming.  :)

Comment: Yes I was in a hurry last night so I couldn't write clearly.  Sorry

Comment: @SencerYazıcı, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize` .  So we may compare similar cases with hardware.